# What format to store large amount of mixed data

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I need your guys opinion how to store this kind of data as I am still a beginner so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I need to store a lot of data in my app as shown in picture to have it accessible for calcs.

I tried to do it using Struct but I will have to assign each row to a variable and I don't want to have hundreds. I would rather use array but don't know if mixed types will not make it more complicated.

```
struct sectionPropertiesUKB {
   let name : String
   let mass : Double
   let depth : Double
   let width : Double
   let tw : Double
   let tf : Double
   let r : Double
   let d : Double
   let cfOverTf: Double
   let cwOverTw: Double
   let C : Double
   let N : Int
   let n : Int
   let SurfaceAperMeter : Double
   let SurfaceAperTonne : Double
   let Iyy : Int
   let Izz : Int
   let iyy : Double
   let izz : Double
   let Wely : Int
   let Welz : Int
   let Wply : Int
   let Wplz : Int
   let U : Double
   let X : Double
   let Iw : Double
   let It : Int
   let A : Int

init(_ name : String, _ mass : Double, _ depth : Double, _ width : Double, _ tw : Double, _ tf : Double, _ r : Double, _ d : Double, _ cfOverTf: Double, _ cwOverTw: Double, _ C : Double, _ N : Int, _ n : Int, _ SurfaceAperMeter : Double, _ SurfaceAperTonne : Double, _ Iyy : Int, _ Izz : Int, _ iyy : Double, _ izz : Double, _ Wely : Int, _ Welz : Int, _ Wply : Int, _ Wplz : Int, _ U : Double, _ X : Double, _ Iw : Double, _ It : Int, _ A : Int)
{
    self.name = name
    self.mass = mass
    self.depth = depth
    self.width = width
    self.tw = tw
    self.tf = tf
    self.r = r
    self.d = d
    self.cfOverTf = cfOverTf
    self.cwOverTw = cwOverTw
    self.C = C
    self.N = N
    self.n = n
    self.SurfaceAperMeter = SurfaceAperMeter
    self.SurfaceAperTonne = SurfaceAperTonne
    self.Iyy = Iyy
    self.Izz = Izz
    self.iyy = iyy
    self.izz = izz
    self.Wely = Wely
    self.Welz = Welz
    self.Wply = Wply
    self.Wplz = Wplz
    self.U = U
    self.X = X
    self.Iw = Iw
    self.It = It
    self.A = A

}

init()
{
    self.init("",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0)

}

let b1 = sectionPropertiesUKB("1016x305x487",486.7,1036.3,308.5,30.0,54.1,30.0,868.1,20.2,28.9,17,150,86,3.2,6.58,1022000,26700,40.6,6.57,19700,1730,23200,2800,0.867,21.1,64.4,4300,620)
```

Is there a better and simpler way how to store this?

I don't want to define b1 to b333 variables. Will core-data be an answer?
Thanks for any help.

[image: Data Example]

Comment: What do you want with all these measurements once it's in digital format?

Comment: I need to use them in various static calculations. Let's say user selects 914x419x388 section I need then to perform calculations say area of flange = 914x419x388.tf * 914x419x388.b. something like that so I probably to access it globally.

Comment: Find an intern or junior employee to enter all that into a spreadsheet. Or get a scanner and see how much OCR can help you. Data entry for that many number is simple but tedious.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it programmatically in Xcode?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with coding. It's just entering a whole bunch of data. I'd suggest that you use a spreadsheet to type out the data and save it as CSV or some kind of database, like `sqllite`.

Comment: Zoff that was what I asked what kind of storage format would be the best (multidimensional array? but I would have different types in it). I rather don't want a csv file and just create sort of library in swift. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easier way to get your data into your program other than writing/copying the data (probably with the help of OCR).

If you don't want to write the data your code you can also make it in a JSON file and load it. The advantage is that you don't have to write it as code and convert it to an array of your desired type if you need it.

```
// using the resources folder in a playground
// File: Data.json this represents your table (like row = sectionPropertiesUKB)
[
  {"name1" : [3.5,  7.4,  3.9]},
  {"name2" : [354,  7,    4.2]},
  {"name3" : [5.6,  1.3,  9.3]},
  {"name4" : [8.7,  2.2,  3.4]}
]

// a struct like you have
struct Sample {
    let name: String
    let length: Double
    let width: Double
    let count: Int
}
```

The code below has to be written only once.

Swift 1.2:

```
// get path and contents of the Data.json file
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: ".json")
if let string = String(contentsOfFile: path!) {

    /// data is of type [[String : [Double]]]
    let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! [[String: [Double]]]

    /// mapped data
    let samples: [Sample] = data.map{ (dataPoint: [String : [Double]]) in

        /// row of your table
        let element: (String, [Double]) = Array(dataPoint)[0]
        let el: [Double] = element.1

        // type construction. Since el is of type [Double] some types have to be converted to Int
        return Sample(name: element.0, length: el[0], width: el[1], count: Int(el[2]))
    }
}
```

Swift 2 (try and catch but same `Sample`):

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Data", ofType: ".json")

do {
    let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!)
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [[String: [Double]]]

    let samples: [Sample] = data.map{ dataPoint in
        let element = Array(dataPoint)[0]
        let el = element.1
        return Sample(name: element.0, length: el[0], width: el[1], count: Int(el[2]))
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you want to access them by name you should use a dictionary which can be created like so (by replacing the current declaration of `let samples`):

```
let samplesDict: [String : Sample] = data.reduce([:]) { (var dict, dataPoint) in
    let element = Array(dataPoint)[0]
    let el = element.1
    dict[element.0] = Sample(name: element.0, length: el[0], width: el[1], count: Int(el[2]))
    return dict
}
```

Comment: Thanks Qbyte. I don't have any problem to type in the data. My main problem was what type of storage to use (multidimensional array?) and how can I access it? I tried with struct but I have to assign each row to variable b1,b2,b3..what I do not want to do. I tried to put variables b1,b2.. into array but got an error about an early assignment. Is there any better way?

Comment: @ste4lth In my example I use an array of structs (`let samples: [Sample]` and your case `[sectionPropertiesUKB]`). So in this case you don't make variables instead you just have to put all the data in a text file.

Comment: @ste4lth This approach models the data/ table one to one. So if you want to access the Samples by name you should rather use a dictionary (added example above).